# How to navigate to another website, pass login information and complete login form in C# ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm trying to create a kind of Auto Login feature in an internal ASP.Net MVC C# tool that will allow support users to quickly login to the various system they support.

I've been able to pass all the values needed to complete the login form via Ajax/jQuery to my controller and then to my Class. As seen below I can open the various URL's based on an if else, but not complete the login form.

I've been looking into httpwebrequests but am not sure how I would structure one to use the variables values (below) to complete the various login form field and then click the button.

```
public AutoLogin(string Environment, string Username, string OrgId, string UserId, string OrgKey)
    {
        var env = Environment;
        var user = Username;
        var org = OrgId;
        var userid = UserId;
        var orgKey = OrgKey;

        if (env == "system1")
        {
            string url = website;

            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            req.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            string username = user;
            string pw = "password";
            string orgUid = orgKey;

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write("userEmail=" + username + "&userPass=" + pw + "&orgUid=" + orgUid);
            sw.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            //Add cookies to CookieJar (Cookie Container)
            foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
            {
                cookieJar.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name.Trim(), cookie.Value.Trim(), cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));
            string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
        }
        else if (env == "system2")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url2);
        }
        else if (env == "system3")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url3);
        }
        else
        {

        } 
    }
```

**Update:**

Added the httpwebrequet code I've been working on but when clicking the button front end it doesn't navigate/open the web page..

Comment: Check SSO  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Comment: @iSahilSharma thanks for the advice but we're not looking at SSO, just need to pass the values from the Tool to the external site's login page and fill the textboxes and login basically.

Comment: Are external sites allowing you to pass user credentials like api calls? In most cases, they don’t.

Answer (score 0):

For internal sites, the easiest way is to use Windows Authentication in your web sites. Just unlock your PC with your password, then go to your internal web sites without login. Windows can do authentication 'under the hood'. Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: They are not internal sites, they are customer facing systems and the support users have their own accounts (username, pw & instance key) to login with. I've got all the values for that, just need to know how to pass them to the website I want to then login too

Comment: You can pass data like user/pw in the Query String, or as POST data, but the question is, how to do it safely.

Comment: Well as the application the values are passed from is an internal support tool and the sites are our products it doesn't hugely matter. The support tool doesn't work outside of our network either.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see how the login form exactly works. Then build that http request in your c# code with a web request.

Comment: added code from doing that, but it doesn't open a new tab with the site. Not sure what I'm missing..